# Topology of compact Alexandrov spaces with nonnegative curvature

Tags: alexandrov-geometry

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact Alexandrov space with nonnegative curvature and $\partial X \ne \emptyset$. If we set $C=\{x\in X \mid d(x, \partial X)=\max_{y \in X} d(y,\partial X)\}$, can we show $B(C,\epsilon):=\{x\in X \mid d(x,C)\le \epsilon\}$ is homeomorphic to $X$, for some sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$?

Comment: I assume you want $\epsilon < \text{diam}(X)$? i.e., asking if for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\epsilon_0 < \epsilon$ which satisfies condition?

Comment: @LorenoHeer Yes, you are right.